# Countable family of continuous functions that separate points and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a second countable and normal space. Show that there is a countable family $F$ of continuous functions from $X$ to $[0,1]$ such that if $x\in X$ and $C$ is closed in $X$ with $x$ is not in $C$, then there is $f\in F$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(C)\subset\{1\}$.

I know this kind of function exist by Urysohn's lemma. However, how to prove that there are countably many? I think this should come from second countability. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $B_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a countable base. Define $P$ the set of all $(n,m) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ such that $\overline{B_n} \subseteq B_m$, which is a countable set. For each $(n,m)$ in $P$ define a Urysohn function $f = f_{(n,m)}:X \rightarrow [0,1]$ (by normality) such that $f[\overline{B_n}] = \{0\}$ and $f[X \setminus B_m] = \{1\}$. I claim that $\{f_{(n,m)}: (n,m) \in P\}$ is as required.

Now, if $x \notin C$ and $C$ closed, then $x \in X\setminus C$, and the latter set is open, so there is some basic open set $B_m$ with $x \in B_m \subseteq X\setminus C$. Then by regularity (I assume the space is $T_1$ as well) there is some basic open set $B_n$ with $x \in B_n \subseteq \overline{B_n} \subseteq B_m$.

So $(n,m) \in P$ and $f = f_{(n,m)}$ is as required, as $f[B_n] = \{0\}$ and $x \in B_n$, while $C \subseteq X\setminus B_m$ and the latter set maps to $1$ under $f = f_{(n,m)}$.

Comment: Thanks for help. Your answer is very clear and helpful.